# Windows 11 installation media creation on chromebooks

Tags: windows-11, iso-image, google-chrome-os

**how do i create a windows recovery media on a chromebook
The ISO has a file that is more than 4 gig**

Comment: Likely not possible due to the reason you already found. In desktop Debian/Ubuntu one can use MKUSB or the multi-boot tool Ventoy that after being installed to the intended USB stick all you have to do is to copy the ISOs to it. Ventoy boots both Linux and Windows ISOs.

Comment: That said, any Windows installation media for UEFI mode only (Windows 11 only supports that mode anyway) can be easily done simply by extracting the contents of the ISO to any USB flash drive formatted as NTFS or exFAT.

Comment: Why exactly are you limited to only 4GB?

Comment: @Ramhound The OP isn't limited, it's the presence of at least one big file that trips most of the traditional tools used to "burn" ISOs to USB in Linux. This happened for all Windows ISOs since some years ago. The OP probably tried with ISO2USB (Android, should be the same or similar in ChromeOS). The problem is any of this tools expect the ISO to be ISO9660 compliant (which has a file size limitation) and current Microsoft offerings aren't. Fortunately it can be done the same way that MKUSB does but manually as I posted in the answer.

Comment: @ChanganAuto - I am familiar with the one big file, so I am confused about why it's a problem since tools exist to address that dilemma. I was trying to determine which tool they used.  That information improves the quality of the question and increases the discoverability of the question and thus any answer it might recieve.

Comment: @Ramhound There aren't that many options in ChromeOS ;-)

Answer (score 1):

As you correctly identified the current Microsoft Windows ISO files don't respect the standard and because of that the typical tools for "burning" and ISO to USB can't be used.

However, the ISO contents can be simply extracted/copied to the USB and the result will be a UEFI mode only bootable installation media. This isn't a limitation because Windows 11 no longer supports the old BIOS/Legacy mode.

**Requirements: Any known good 8GB+ NTFS or exFAT formatted USB flash drive.**

If your media isn't already formatted as described above you can use ChromeOS' Files tools to do it:

1. Open the **Files** app
2. Locate and select the USB flash drive listed on the left panel ("Seagate" in this example
   [image]
3. Right-click the drive
4. Select "Format device"
   [image]
5. Give it a name (optional)
6. Select the file system ("Format") as exFAT or NTFS
   [image]
7. Click "Erase and Format"

Now double-click the ISO to mount it as a drive (ChromeOS 101 or newer support ISO files as well as TAR and ZIP), select all and copy the contents to the newly formatted USB flash drive that because it has now a file system that supports bigger files the copy should be successful. The resulting media should then be bootable in UEFI mode in any compatible computer.